# Pythonic way to get the index of element from a list of dicts depending on multiple keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am very new to python, and I have the following problem. I came up with  the following solution. I am wondering whether it is "pythonic" or not. If not, what would be the best solution ?

The problem is :

- I have a list of dict
- each dict has at least three items
- I want to find the position in the list of the dict with specific three values

This is my python example

```
import collections
import random

# lets build the list, for the example 
dicts = [] 
dicts.append({'idName':'NA','idGroup':'GA','idFamily':'FA'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NA','idGroup':'GA','idFamily':'FB'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NA','idGroup':'GB','idFamily':'FA'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NA','idGroup':'GB','idFamily':'FB'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NB','idGroup':'GA','idFamily':'FA'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NB','idGroup':'GA','idFamily':'FB'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NB','idGroup':'GB','idFamily':'FA'})
dicts.append({'idName':'NB','idGroup':'GB','idFamily':'FB'})


# let's shuffle it, again for example
random.shuffle(dicts)

# now I want to have for each combination the index 

# I use a recursive defaultdict definition 
# because it permits creating a dict of dict 
# even if it is not initialized 

def tree(): return collections.defaultdict(tree)

# initiate mapping 
mapping = tree()

# fill the mapping
for i,d  in enumerate(dicts):        

    idFamily = d['idFamily']
    idGroup = d['idGroup']
    idName = d['idName']

    mapping[idName][idGroup][idFamily] = i

# I end up with the mapping providing me with the index within 
# list of dicts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks reasonable to me, but perhaps a little too much. You could instead do:

```
mapping = {
    (d['idName'], d['idGroup'], d['idFamily']) : i
    for i, d in enumerate(dicts)
}
```

Then access it with `mapping['NA', 'GA', 'FA']` instead of `mapping['NA']['GA']['FA']`. But it really depends how you're planning to use the `mapping`. If you need to be able to take `mapping['NA']` and use it as a dictionary then what you have is fine.

Comment: Many thanks, exactly what I was looking for, your solution is much simpler !